# NetSuite Saved Search formula for Invoice quantity minus Credit Memo quantity

Tags: case, netsuite

Newbie here!
I am trying to do a saved search that would return a summarized quantity of licenses.

As long as today's date is "between or equal to" the contract Start and End date, then I would like the results to give me the Total of quantity in the Invoice minus quantity in the Credit Memo.

So far, I've done this:

CASE WHEN to_date{today} BETWEEN {contract_start_date} AND {contract_end_date} THEN ***Invoice quantity minus Credit Memo quantity***